# Sql Server how to add computed columns to variable and use it in another column

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have the following query

```
GO
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Referencia VARCHAR(15),
    UAP NVARCHAR(20),
    ConsumoWeek01 FLOAT,
    ConsumoWeek02 FLOAT,
    Stock INT,
    PecasPorCaixa INT
    UNIQUE (Id)
)

INSERT INTO
    @tempTable
SELECT *
FROM
    viewConsumoPDP

SELECT 
    C.Id,
    C.Referencia,
    C.UAP,
    C.ConsumoWeek01 AS ConsumoInicialWeek01,
    T.ConsumoWeek01 AS ConsumoActualWeek01,
    T.ConsumoWeek01 / 5 AS ConsumoDiarioWeek01,
    T.ConsumoWeek02 AS ConsumoWeek02
FROM 
    @tempTable T
INNER JOIN Parametros P
ON P.Referencia = T.Referencia 
AND P.UAP = T.UAP
INNER JOIN Consumos C
ON C.Referencia = P.Referencia
AND C.UAP = P.UAP
```

I need to create some variables that are calculated using some columns values and I need to use that variable to calculate other columns.

Reason why is because I don't want to do all calculations on the select statement and it will be a big confusion but I have no idea if it is possible using SQL Transact.

For example

```
GO
    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
    (
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        Referencia VARCHAR(15),
        UAP NVARCHAR(20),
        ConsumoWeek01 FLOAT,
        ConsumoWeek02 FLOAT,
        Stock INT,
        PecasPorCaixa INT
        UNIQUE (Id)
    )

    DECLARE @NumPAB INT

    INSERT INTO
        @tempTable
    SELECT *
    FROM
        viewConsumoPDP

    SELECT 
        C.Id,
        C.Referencia,
        C.UAP,
        C.ConsumoWeek01 AS ConsumoInicialWeek01,
        T.ConsumoWeek01 AS ConsumoActualWeek01,
        T.ConsumoWeek01 / 5 AS ConsumoDiarioWeek01,
        T.ConsumoWeek02 AS ConsumoWeek02,
        @ConsumoPAB = P.NumPab / T.ConsumoWeek01                 
    FROM 
        @tempTable T
    INNER JOIN Parametros P
    ON P.Referencia = T.Referencia 
    AND P.UAP = T.UAP
    INNER JOIN Consumos C
    ON C.Referencia = P.Referencia
    AND C.UAP = P.UAP
```

You can see i'd like to store the result of the calculation in a variable and later use it in another computed column. But how to achieve this if i cannot assign the value within the select statement?

Comment: I know i can use temporary table but i rarely notice any difference compared to table variable

Comment: It depends on the version of SQL Server, but older versions assuma variable contains 1 row; which can impact performance due to poor query plan choices (more recent versions are better (aka 2017+)).

Comment: I see, I assume i can add index to this temp table like i'm doing on table variable tho?

Comment: I don;'t really understand what you're after here. You can't assign a variable in the same statement that you return data in, I *assume* `@ConsumoPAB` is a scalar variable (you don't `DECLARE` it in your SQL), but still you can't assign a dataset to a scalar variable either. Sample data & expected results might help here.

Comment: I see that's sad though. I was looking to simplify having to write so many formulas and repeating on every column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `SELECT` statement, you can return a result set **OR** assign values to variables. You can't do both operations at the same time.

The main reason is that both operations are logically different. One will handle a set of values, while the other will handle scalar values.

Comment: Is there a way to simplify having to write many formulas on the select statement though?

Comment: There are several ways, it depends on what you're trying to do. You could use CTEs or the APPLY operator for starters. You could use real computed columns instead of calculating them in the code.

Comment: Could you tell me what CTE stands for?

Comment: [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) which is like having an inline single-use view.